# How can I set the labels of Material-Table selection checkboxes?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, material-table

I'm working on a React web application that uses several Material-Tables. Currently, I'm auditing the application for accessibility issues using the axe-core testing engine. "Selection" is set to true in the Options for the Material-Tables, so multiple rows can be selected via checkboxes ([examples here](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/selection)). Axe-core informs me that "Form elements must have labels", and this [warning](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.7/label?application=axeAPI) is issued for each checkbox of each row of the tables. How can I add labels or set aria-labels for these checkboxes?

In the Options of one such MaterialTable, I tried setting the label with selectionProps:

```
options={{
    selection: true,
    selectionProps: rowData => ({
      label: 'Select',
    })
 }}
```

However, this did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox in the table header row should really say "select all" even though having a checkbox in a table header is kind of a common UX pattern to mean "select all". Some users might not be familiar with that pattern.

And then normally, a table column header label is sufficient for all the checkboxes in that column but in this case, the header is "select all" but each row's checkbox is **not** a "select all" but just a "select this row".

From a sighted user's perspective, the checkbox on a row might be a familiar pattern for selecting a row so you don't necessarily need a visible label that says "select" ([WCAG 3.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#labels-or-instructions) doesn't require a *visible* label, although that's a best practice) but you **do** need a "label" for assistive technology, such as a screen reader.  Currently, the screen reader will just say "checkbox" and the user won't know what it's for.  You need to inject an `aria-label="select row"` on the <input type="checkbox">.

As far as *how* to inject that code with material, I'm not sure.  But I wanted to give some accessibility background.

It would also help satisfy WCAG 3.3.2 if you had an instruction line somewhere that said "to select a row, select the checkbox at the beginning of the row. to select all rows, select the checkbox on the table header" (or something like that).

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I'm looking for is how to inject the aria-label into the checkboxes.